# CSS slide in from left animation

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a slideshow and it works, except for the animations. The animation for sliding out works fine but the animation for sliding in from the left does not. The left margin gets set to 0% but there is no animation, even though it is set to -100% at first.

Javascript:

```js
var images = [
    'http://i.imgur.com/ByyUANz.png',
    'http://i.imgur.com/S5FfOOB.png',
    'http://i.imgur.com/EuefPdv.png',
    'http://i.imgur.com/Ucvm4pJ.png',
    'http://i.imgur.com/pK5WBHN.png',
    'http://i.imgur.com/nuOLVpy.png'
]
 
function slideShow(startAt){
    var holder = document.getElementById("currentImage");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = images[startAt];
    holder.appendChild(img);
    nextPicture(startAt, img);
}
  
function nextPicture(current, currentElement){
 
    var holder = document.getElementById("currentImage");
    setTimeout(function(){
        currentElement.className = "translateLeft";
        current += 1;
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = images[current];
        img.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  
        holder.appendChild(img);
        img.className = "translateIn";
    
        if (current == 5){
            current = -1;
            nextPicture(current, img);
        } else {
            nextPicture(current, img);
        }
    
    }, 5000)
   
}
  
slideShow(0);
```

CSS:

```css
.translateLeft {    
    transition: 3s;
    margin-left: 100% !important;
}
   
.translateIn {
   
    transition: 3s;
    margin-left: 0% !important;   
}
```

Comment: Any chance at getting a plunker, fiddle or snippet?  This would be a lot easier to fix if we could look at it and debug it in realtime...

Comment: Remove all javascript and use css @keyframes

Comment: Where is the DOM (HTML)

Comment: @anied https://jsfiddle.net/smaefwrp/

Comment: So is the issue that no image appears at all after the first slide?  Because that's what's happening in the fiddle...

Comment: No, if you scroll down you'll see it appears @anied

Comment: What exactly is your objective here? Do you want to make somthing like [this](http://fotorama.io/#unsplash__cd8dfa25-2bc5-4546-995a-f3fd23809e1d)

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code also?

Comment: @NahushFarkande yes, except that I want it to change every 5 seconds on its own.

Comment: @Nitheesh here's the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/smaefwrp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for you. 
https://jsfiddle.net/smaefwrp/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body,
        img {
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #currentImage {
            height: 100%;
            width: 1920px;
        }
        .translateOrigin {
            transition: none;
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) !important;
        }

        .translateLeft {
            transition: transform 3s;
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) !important;
        }

        .translateIn {
            transition: transform 3s;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="currentImage">
</div>
<div id="buttons">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = [
        'http://i.imgur.com/ByyUANz.png',
        'http://i.imgur.com/S5FfOOB.png',
        'http://i.imgur.com/EuefPdv.png',
        'http://i.imgur.com/Ucvm4pJ.png',
        'http://i.imgur.com/pK5WBHN.png',
        'http://i.imgur.com/nuOLVpy.png'
    ];
    var imageEle = [];
    var currImage = 0;
    var holder = document.getElementById("currentImage");

    function imagesPreload() {
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = images[i];
            img.className = "translateOrigin";
            holder.appendChild(img);
            imageEle.push(img);
        }
    }

    imagesPreload();

    document.onkeydown = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 13) {
            nextPicture();
        }
    };

    function slideShow(startAt) {
        var holder = document.getElementById("currentImage");
        imageEle[currImage].className = "translateIn";
        nextPicture();
    }

    function nextPicture() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var img = imageEle[currImage];
            img.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionEnd, false);
            img.className = "translateLeft";

            if (currImage == 5) {
                currImage = 0;
            } else {
                currImage++;
            }
            imageEle[currImage].className = "translateIn";

            /* Reset the image to original position */
            function transitionEnd() {
                img.className = "translateOrigin";
                img.removeEventListener("transitionend", transitionEnd, false);
                nextPicture();
            }
        }, 5000)
    }
    slideShow(currImage);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

To create a nice slideshow I suggest to use css `transform` property rather than the `margin`. The idea is to create the placeholder element `currentImage` with `relative` position, and then create all images inside it with position set to `absolute`. Then by default all images are translated out of the placeholder element, and adding/removing classes `show` and `hide` you can place them inside the view and then outside of it, like this:

```js
var images = [
  'http://i.imgur.com/ByyUANz.png',
  'http://i.imgur.com/S5FfOOB.png',
  'http://i.imgur.com/EuefPdv.png',
  'http://i.imgur.com/Ucvm4pJ.png',
  'http://i.imgur.com/pK5WBHN.png',
  'http://i.imgur.com/nuOLVpy.png'
];

// Get the holder
var holder = document.getElementById("currentImage");

// Create the images
images.forEach(function(url) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = url;
  holder.appendChild(img);
});

// Image counter
var counter = 0;

// Slide show interval
var slideshow = setInterval(function() {
  // When we reach the end of images we shut down the slide show
  // or you can reset the counter to start over
  if(counter === images.length) {
    clearInterval(slideshow);
    return;
  }
  
  // Get all images
  var nodes = holder.getElementsByTagName("img");
  
  // Hide previous image
  if(nodes[counter - 1]) {
   nodes[counter - 1].className = "hide";
  }
  // Show next image
  nodes[counter].className = "show";
  
  counter++;
}, 2500);
```

```css
#currentImage {
  background: gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#currentImage img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.0s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1.0s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1.0s ease 0s;
  transition: transform 1.0s ease 0s;
}

#currentImage img.show {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

#currentImage img.hide {
  transform: translateX(110%);
}
```

```html
<div id="currentImage">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
// HTML
<div id="currentImage">
  <div class="window">
    <div class="image-list">
      <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ByyUANz.png" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/S5FfOOB.png" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EuefPdv.png" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ucvm4pJ.png" />
      </div>

      <div>
         <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pK5WBHN.png" />
       </div>

      <div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nuOLVpy.png" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
// CSS
img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px
}

.window {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden
}
div {
  display: inline-block

}
.image-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 350px;
  animation: slidingli 30s ; 
}

@keyframes slidingli {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }

  16% {
    transform: translateX(-50px)
  }

  32% {
    transform: translateX(-100px)
  }

  48% {
    transform: translateX(-150px)
  }

  64% {
    transform: translateX(-200px)
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateX(-250px)
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-300px)
  }
}
```

Checkout [this](https://jsfiddle.net/NahushF/dnzx8m1f/) fiddle. Also there are many libraries out there which provide what need For example: http://fotorama.io/customize/autoplay/